# IBOutletCollection and multiple objects of different "kinds" not working as expected. Who knows why?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm trying to use an outlet colleciton as a basis for segue filtering instead of Identifier, but when I add objects to the outlet collection (defined generically using id; see below), I find only UI elements OR other non-ui elements are actually added to the collection not both. Let me be clear, IB lets you seemingly add the objects to the collection. Say add a button and a label then a gesture recognizer. This works in IB without error or warning, but when queryed at runtime, the collection contains only the UI type elements. The gesture recognizer is nowhere to be found, but add only the gesture recognizer and it will be present in the collection. Does anyone know why?

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(id) NSArray *myCollection;`